# delete_scalar_size.cpp not found in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, destructor

I run a program with some destructors and it works fine until debug mode.
When its making a delete or delete [] this error shows up: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a20B.jpg.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a20B.jpg)

I mention that I run again the installer in repair mode and nothing happened.

**WebServices.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "WebServices.h"

using namespace std;

WebServices::WebServices(char* name, char* customerName)
{
    m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_name, strlen(name) + 1, name);
    m_customerName = new char[strlen(customerName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_customerName, strlen(customerName) + 1, customerName);
//  m_noActiveServices++;
}

WebServices::WebServices(const WebServices &a)
{
    m_name = new char[strlen(a.m_name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_name, strlen(a.m_name) + 1, a.m_name);
    m_customerName = new char[strlen(a.m_customerName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_customerName, strlen(a.m_customerName) + 1, a.m_customerName);
}

void WebServices::setName(char* name)
{
    m_name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_name, strlen(name) + 1, name);
}

void WebServices::setCustomerName(char* customerName)
{
    m_customerName = new char[strlen(customerName) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_customerName, strlen(customerName) + 1, customerName);
}
void WebServices::read()
{
    char aux[100];
    cout << "Insert name for WebService: ";
    cin.getline(aux, 99);
    m_name = new char[strlen(aux) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_name, strlen(aux) + 1, aux);
    cout << "Customer name: ";
    cin.getline(aux, 99);
    m_customerName = new char[strlen(aux) + 1];
    strcpy_s(m_customerName, strlen(aux) + 1, aux);
}

void WebServices::print()
{
    cout << "Web Service: " << m_name;
    cout << "\tCustomer Name: " << m_customerName;
}
```

**WebServices.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Services.h"

using namespace std;

class WebServices : public Services
{
private:
    char* m_name;
    char* m_customerName;
//  static int m_noActiveServices;

public:
    WebServices() : m_name(nullptr), m_customerName(nullptr) {};
    WebServices (char* name, char* customerName);
    WebServices(const WebServices &a);

    ~WebServices() {if (nullptr != m_name) delete m_name;
        if (nullptr != m_customerName) delete m_customerName;
    }
    char* getName() {
        return m_name;
    }
    char* getCustomerName() {
        return m_customerName;
    }
    void setName(char* name);
    void setCustomerName(char* customerName);

    void read();
    void print();
    virtual double estimatePrice() { return 0; };

};
```

Also, it's working on another machine using the same version of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Do you also have a code example where you use `delete[]` since you mention it in your question?

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @vonludi, I tried to use delete [] for a char*, I know that it's not fine, but tried in scope of expecting a some error at deleting the memory, but it's same error with not founded cpp

Comment: I'm still not sure what you expect us to do. Do you want us to point you to the source file in question (`delete_scalar_size.cpp`)?

Comment: It's normal to not have that file, it's part of the memory manager implementation. What's happened is that some of your code is seriously broken. Start looking in `~DomainRegistrar`, the root of the creash in your own code.

Comment: And read about "the rule of three" (use a search engine).

Comment: I moved all the files into another project and it's working now. Probably some bad configuration in my project options.